# how to sort sql results by conditions?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

My mysql query is:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE age > 20 OR name LIKE %ali%");
```

I used this query in this php source:

```
while($result = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
    echo 'name:' . $result['name'] . ' -->> age: '. $result['age'] . '<br/>';
}
```

My result is like this:

alireza -->> 21
mohammad -->> 23
ehsan -->> 28
alizade -->> 32
fardin -->> 22
aliahmad -->>35

But I want first display results where "ali" is in their name then display results where their age is bigger than 20 like this:

alireza -->> 21
aliahmad -->>35
alizade -->> 32
mohammad -->> 23
ehsan -->> 28
fardin -->> 22

exceuse me because i can not speak in english good. My language is persian.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: In your sql query, try using `ORDER BY`. You can do multiple order bys so you can make it display by any criteria. See the MySQL manual for more info.

Comment: See the MySQL manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: I am not a professional programmer. plaese give me a source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add conditions to an `ORDER BY` clause.

In your case, you would need something like:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN name LIKE %ali% THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END,
  age
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add priority and then sort by this new column

```
SELECT name, age, IF(name LIKE '%ali%', 1, 0) as priority FROM persons 
WHERE age > 20 OR name LIKE %ali% ORDER BY priority DESC
```

Answer (score -3):

Use below

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE age > 20 OR name LIKE %ali%" order by age);
```

Comment: age is the secondary order by with names starting with `ali` being the first.